# Могу ли я написать бота, который будет отвечать на сообщения, приходящие на МОЮ учётную запись?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, бот

Все боты в телеграмме представляют собой отдельный аккаунт, который отвечает на запланированные сообщения. Могу ли я написать бота, который будет отвечать на сообщения, приходящие на МОЮ учётную запись?
Если да, то можете подсказать дельные гайды?

Answer (score 2):

Вы можете воспользоваться [pyrogram](https://github.com/pyrogram/pyrogram) или [Telethon](https://docs.telethon.dev/en/latest/).
Они позволяют отправлять сообщения от своего имени.

Для получения `api_id` и `api_hash` посетите https://my.telegram.org/auth

Пример отправки сообщения в группу от своего имени на pyrogram:

```
from pyrogram import Client

app = Client(
    session_name="pyro",
    proxy=dict(
        hostname="",
        port=1080,
        username="",
        password=""),
    api_id='1...1',
    api_hash='f1...62')

app.start()

app.send_message(chat_id=-26...72, text='https://goo.gl')

app.stop()
```